# Windows Authentication when calling a WCF service using Jquery

Tags: jquery, authentication, sharepoint-2013

I am having a jquery file which is embedded inside SharePoint on premise environment. I want to call a WCF service which has windows authentication enabled. 
I have enabled CORS and added the headers like ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","requested domain"),("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
 ("Cache-Control", "no-cache").

The ajax call is as below:-

```
//ajax
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: successCallback,
    contentType: "application/json",
crossDomain: true,
   xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    error: errorCallback,
    dataType: "json"
})
}
```

But making a service call is giving Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. I am using IE11 browser.

Can you please help me how can I pass current logged in user credential to make my service call.

Comment: Is it SP2013 onpremise?

Comment: yes it is SP2013 on premise

Comment: Try the links I given below.And see if that can help you